# Straighten my corners... diagonally

Tags: code-golf, sequence, grid

We can arrange the positive integers like this:

```
1_| 2 | 5 | 10
4___3_| 6 | 11
9___8___7_| 12
16  15  14  13
```

That is, in L-shaped brackets expanding down and right infinitely.

Then, we can read it off with the antidiagonals:

```
1 2 5  10
 / /  /
4 3  6  11
 /  /  /
9  8  7  12
  /  /  /
16 15 14  13
```

For the above, we read `1`, then `2, 4`, then `5, 3, 9`, then `10, 6, 8, 16`, and so on.

Your challenge is to output this sequence. Standard [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) rules apply. This is [A060736](https://oeis.org/A060736).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

Answer (score 10):

## x86-64 machine code, <del>25</del> 23 bytes

```
31 C0 48 01 C1 7F FB 29 C8 29 C1 7F 03 01 C8 48 01 C1 F7 E8 01 C8 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVGxboMwEJ3xV1ypItmBRGkidSAhS@cunSo1FTLGgCtjKgytUZRfLzUE0jQezr537@4922yRMdZ190Ix2SQcdrpORLnM9@gfJEV8i1VCZT2GoojWNoubmkcRxinVNaNSEgJC1ZDiPlKyRVQXgOHFxWiZyTKmElKUBo4pK@DU@H1AVeAknA1HhyYJcDYWnI8MKuToJh7JzIzZNUOPXRfGNEwHN@NE0cgrmUtDxWtEXLB2Ue@7oEKdL1BlzAeW0wrmc5t8EXREYFdfNBDCyoe237YD@p0LyQF7noFdCA@PZED79WnfrU6xOxOw2MNMHJTrg1VPsSHk3DxRDuqZslwoDqxMeOCOZfMnk5RwnNgwW61f7aw2xLhRWmSKJ4PhOUnJm/G8d7I9TcZauLNDzNPmRhKw9RW3NdfkbGys22dpKtXLnlDX/bBU0kx3i2KztsF@bGjbufwF)

Following the `fastcall` calling convention, this takes a number *n* in ECX and returns the 1-indexed *n*th entry in EAX.

This works by first determining x and y coordinates in the grid. Then, letting m = min(x,y), the result is m<sup>2</sup>+m+1+y-x.

```
 │ 0 1 2 
─┼─┴─┴─┴x
0┤ 1 2 5
1┤ 4 3 6
2┤ 9 8 7
 y
```

In assembly:

```
f:  xor eax, eax    # Set EAX to 0.
r:  dec eax         # Subtract 1 from EAX.
                    # This will be the negative length of the current diagonal.
    add ecx, eax    # Add EAX to ECX.
    jg r            # Jump back if the result is positive --
                    #   if the index given has not been reached.
                    # When the loop ends, ECX will hold the negative 0-indexed reverse
                    #   position of the given index within its diagonal, equal to -x.
                    # EAX will hold the negative length of the diagonal, -x-y-1.
    sub eax, ecx    # Subtract ECX from EAX; EAX now holds -y-1.
    sub ecx, eax    # Subtract EAX from ECX, making ECX y-x+1.
    jg s            # Jump if that's positive.
    add eax, ecx    # (Otherwise: y<x) Add ECX to EAX, making EAX -x.
    dec eax         # Subtract 1 from EAX, making -x-1.
                    # Either way, EAX ends up as -m-1.
s:  add ecx, eax    # Add EAX to ECX, making ECX y-x-m.
    imul eax        # Multiply EAX by itself, making (-m-1)² = m²+2m+1.
    add eax, ecx    # Add ECX to EAX, making m²+m+1+y-x.
    ret             # Return.
```

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES7), 49 bytes

Returns the \$n\$-th term, 1-indexed.

```javascript
n=>(t=(2*n)**.5+.5|0,t-=n-=t*~-t/2)<n?n*n-t:t*t+n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcq9DoIwFAbQnae4A0N/LCpJF@Hqq9AgGA35auDGpdZXr2xnOK/wCdu4Pt/iEO9TmbmAr0pYtQbamMbbxn9PB3EMx2J@To6t7nGDgZOLGLEoc1wViOncEahn8n6HtZpSRTRGbHGZmiU@1BBUnZD1fus0K@g86K7K5Q8)

#### How?

This is a revamped version of the 2nd formula given on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A060736).

We define the 1-based index \$t\$ of the diagonal to which the \$n\$-th entry belongs (this is [A002024](https://oeis.org/A002024)):

$$t=\left\lfloor\sqrt{2n}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$$

We define the 1-based index \$N\$ representing the position of the entry in the diagonal (from top-right to bottom-left):

$$N=n-\frac{t(t-1)}{2}$$

We turn it into an index \$T\$ going from \$t-1\$ to \$0\$:

$$T=t-N$$

The figures below represent \$n\$, \$t\$, \$N\$ and \$T\$ respectively:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}1&2&\color{red}4&7\\
3&\color{red}5&8\\
\color{red}6&9\\
10
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}1&2&\color{red}3&4\\
2&\color{red}3&4\\
\color{red}3&4\\
4
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}1&1&\color{red}1&1\\
2&\color{red}2&2\\
\color{red}3&3\\
4
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}0&1&\color{red}2&3\\
0&\color{red}1&2\\
\color{red}0&1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$

The final result is given by:

$$\cases{N^2-T,&\text{if $T<N$}\\T^2+N,&\text{if $T\ge N$}}$$

Leading to:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}1&2&\color{red}5&10\\
4&\color{red}3&6\\
\color{red}9&8\\
16
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 40 bytes

```
[k^2+k-n*min(2*k-n)1|n<-[1..],k<-[1..n]]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ2W0km6Ec0CAUuz-3MTMPAVbhdzEAt94hYKizLwSBRWFksTsVAVDAwOFmKWlJWm6Fjc1orPjjLSzdfO0cjPzNIy0gCxNw5o8G91oQz29WJ1sCCMvNhaifgGUgtIA)

-2 bytes thanks to [@ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs).

Based on the Mathematica code on OEIS.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>44</sup> 39 bytes

```
{.&;[:</.@(*+/\"1@,._1+<:/*2*]"0/)~1+i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYvNCsIwEITvfYqhStu066Yb/2OVoOBJPHitRUEU9eIDiH31mujhY4bdb55dzOkNS4sUhBLWM2BsDrtt9@ZkUdtKs8vyQh9jccQnKSqrc5M3calVK8WDOxXt1wwpmjD46eTqc3OuP/2sZ7XNVqxJcJIkV65nFSn3YEdtFF0v9xduMOW/CcEQRoQxYUiYE6QkTAgz33zI1OOlEF4xgXAObz8UvzSj7gs)

The formula might have been shorter, but I wanted to construct the matrix and use J's `/.` adverb to get the diagonals, because when you have a primitive to get diagonals you cannot not use it.

To construct the matrix, note that the successive deltas have an easy to describe pattern that looks like this:

```
 1  3  5  7  9 11 13
_1  3  5  7  9 11 13
_1 _1  5  7  9 11 13
_1 _1 _1  7  9 11 13
_1 _1 _1 _1  9 11 13
_1 _1 _1 _1 _1 11 13
_1 _1 _1 _1 _1 _1 13
```

and that the first column are the squares.  So we just zip them together:

```
 1  1  3  5  7  9 11 13
 4 _1  3  5  7  9 11 13
 9 _1 _1  5  7  9 11 13
16 _1 _1 _1  7  9 11 13
25 _1 _1 _1 _1  9 11 13
36 _1 _1 _1 _1 _1 11 13
49 _1 _1 _1 _1 _1 _1 13
```

and then scan sum each row to reproduce the matrix:

```
 1  2  5 10 17 26 37 50
 4  3  6 11 18 27 38 51
 9  8  7 12 19 28 39 52
16 15 14 13 20 29 40 53
25 24 23 22 21 30 41 54
36 35 34 33 32 31 42 55
49 48 47 46 45 44 43 56
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 67 bytes

```
n=0
while n:=n+1:[print(k*k+k-n*min(2*k-n,1))for k in range(1,n+1)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3nfNsDbjKMzJzUhXyrGzztA2toguKMvNKNLK1srWzdfO0cjPzNIy0gCwdQ03NtPwihWyFzDyFosS89FQNQx2gBs1YiFFQE2EmAwA)

Port of Haskell. Outputs infinitely.

Old answer:

### [Python](https://www.python.org), 77 bytes

```
n=0
while n:=n+1:[print(n<2*k-1and-~k*k-n or(n-k)**2+k)for k in range(1,n+1)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3ffNsDbjKMzJzUhXyrGzztA2toguKMvNKNPJsjLSydQ0T81J067KBrDyF_CKNPN1sTS0tI-1szbT8IoVshcw8haLEvPRUDUMdoFbNWIihULNhdgAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>86</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>60</s></sup> 55 bytes

```c
t;f(n){t=sqrt(2*n)+.5;n=(t-=n-=t*~-t/2)<n?n*n-t:t*t+n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDRTsIwFH3nK26WkHRbK6xjKpbpg/ErHA@kdLgIBdebuEjmpztvx0Bpctrbc8856a0WG627DlXJbHjE3H3UyGRkw/gmUzZnKHIrcoy@BU5kuLBPNrICHzDC2Kq2qyzCblVZFsJxBLQ8YZqD0WjWr0vI4ZhwkBxmHDIOKYc5h2TK4ZbDPVV0JHcEEvmDJNLD075NxoSckpASl5JGep0PoSxJSEk/o3tGoSl5pAfVkrzprFX9q/TeOgT9tqoj2o1@N/XpcUHRvMiimT8TsoDD/3saDO5yXwPzg1V2bRqyTdVQLsBVX2ZfsvPI4WQgogujII57ddiHnb7p/FVIaaeoGBJ11XLUKhmG16wh9vK/vXP5JzjUJClZMF6DeATax66wNBVycPwyuMtzsxxi21Hb/ehyu9q4Tnx2Yrv7BQ)

*Saved a whopping 13 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!*
*Saved yet another a whopping <s>13</s> 18 bytes thanks to the man himself [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!*

Returns the \$n^\text{th}\$ term.
Uses the formula from [A060736](https://oeis.org/A060736).

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), <s>86</s> 83 bytes

```factor
0 [ 1 + 3 dupn [1,b] [ 3 dupn sq + -rot 2 * over - 1 min * - . ] with each t ] loop
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY0xDoJAEEWv8msVItoYPYCxMTHEilCsMMBG2F2GQaNXsaHRO3EbN0r182be_Hl9CpWJ5WE8nePDcb9Fo6QKWZmSOlyJDdUoyRCrWj-VaGu6n_L3LOfE6KjtyWT-wDGJPBxrI9i9eymCzRgvkSDCHGvkvTNIosUl9aMJu9avAraCFWawN98XeL3RxmOAECnu2v8jlVUQT7W17l89TDHlFw)

Outputs the sequence indefinitely. Loosely based on alephalpha's [Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247866/97916).

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 83 bytes

```
.+
*
(^_|\1_)*(_+)
$.2*$2$2,$.1*$($1___)__-$.2*2*$($1_);$1_
,|(_+)-\1_*

(_+);\1

_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYsxDoMwEAT7fcdFsg9scZeQgHgAn0DZpEiRJkVEyd8NFs1oNdr5f9bv723lEuZXyQ0U4cltMUYNbCIku4qLt5JNJYiRjGSq3k8RpwNot/pPR6lAndNiAEsxOK64occdDwwYYd0O) Link includes test cases. Outputs the `n`th term. Explanation: Loosely based on @alephalpha's formula.

```
.+
*
```

Convert `n` to unary.

```
(^_|\1_)*(_+)
```

Decompose `n` into a triangular number `t-1` and a residue `k` in the range `1..t`.

```
$.2*$2$2,$.1*$($1___)__-$.2*2*$($1_);$1_
```

Calculate `k*k+k`, `t*t+t`, `2*k*t` and `t`.

```
,|(_+)-\1_*
```

Subtract `2*k*t` from `t*t+t`, clamping the result at `0`, and add on `k*k+k`.

```
(_+);\1
```

Subtract `t` from the previous result.

```
_
```

Convert to decimal.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
[¼¾ENnN+¾N·¾-1‚ß*-,
```

Port of [*@alephalpha*'s Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247866/52210).

Outputs indefinitely.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9vc2FiaWX//1vCvMK@RU5uTivCvk7Ct8K@LTHigJrDnyotLP//)

**Explanation:**

```python
[                   # Loop indefinitely:
 ¼                  #  Increase variable `c` by 1 (0 by default)
  ¾E                #  Inner loop `N` in the range [1,`c`]:
                  , #   Pop and output:
    NnN+¾N·¾-1‚ß*-  #    N²+N-c*min(2N-c,1)
    Nn              #    N²
      N+            #      +N
                 -  #        -
        ¾       *   #         c*
             1‚ß    #           min(    ,1)
         N·         #               2N
           ¾-       #                 -c
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
⇧Þ□λ÷N^›WDṘ²+^∑1<i;ÞZÞḋIRfi
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLih6fDnuKWoc67w7dOXuKAuldE4bmYwrIrXuKIkTE8aTvDnlrDnuG4i0lSZmkiLCIiLCIyIl0=)

Based on [@Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s [Javascript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247864/103205).

–1 per [@emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/emanresu-a).

### How?

```
λ÷N^›WDṘ²+^∑1<i; # find the (i, j)th entry of the matrix
λ              ; # lambda           STACK (top ->)
 ÷               # unwrap           i j
  N              # negate           i -j
   ^             # reverse stack    -j i
    ›            # increment        -j i+1
     W           # wrap             [i+1,-j]
                 #                = [N,-T] (using Arnaud's notation)
      D          # triplicate       [N,-T] [N,-T] [N,-T]
       Ṙ         # reverse          [N,-T] [N,-T] [-T,N]
        ²        # square           [N,-T] [N,-T] [T^2,N^2]
         +       # sum              [N,-T] [T^2+N,N^2-T]
          ^      # reverse stack    [T^2+N,N^2-T] [N,-T]
           ∑     # sum              [T^2+N,N^2-T] N-T
            1<   # is < 1?          [T^2+N,N^2-T] (1 if N-T<1 else 0)
                 #                = [T^2+N,N^2-T] (1 if T>=N else 0)
              i  # index            N^2-T if T>=N else T^2+N

⇧Þ□λ÷N^›WDṘ²+^∑1<i;ÞZ # make the matrix
⇧                     # double increment, pushing N+2
 Þ□                   # (Nx2)x(Nx2) identity matrix
   λ÷N^›WDṘ²+^∑1<i;   # (above function)
                   ÞZ # fill by coordinates, i.e. replace each entry
                      # of the matrix with the result of calling the
                      # function on the entry's list of coordinates

ÞḋIRfi # output              example (3x3 matrix)
Þḋ     # antidiagonals       [[5,3,9],[2,4],[1],[7],[6,8]]
  I    # into two pieces     [ [[5,3,9],[2,4],[1]] , [[7],[6,8]] ]
   R   # vectorized reverse  [ [[1],[2,4],[5,3,9]] , [[6,8],[7]] ]
    f  # flatten             [1,2,4,5,3,9,6,8,7]
     i # index by input
```

Comment: Nice answer! `i` also works with (num, list) so you can shave off the `⁰` at the end. If you need any help with Vyxal, the [Vyxal chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106764/vyxal) exists, and there's also a [deadlineless bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22137/100664) for Vyxal answers.

Comment: By the way, in Vyxal, `#` is the line comment character (i.e. the interpreter ignores it and chars after it), so we typically use that for explanation comments

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/),  72 bytes

*-18 bytes thanks to the formula of `Arnauld` and -10 bytes thanks to `Kevin Cruijssen`.*

```python
lambda n:(t:=int((2*n)**.5+.5),(n:=n-t*~-t/2)*n-(t:=t-n),t*t+n)[2-(t<n)]
```

[Attempt this online](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYxBCsIwEEX3nmJ2nUmTSgMVCWbvHdRFRaOBOi1lXEipF3FTEL2Tt9FSVw8-77_Hu7nJuebhGfz2dZVglp91VV72hxLYoTgfWRCtYlIqK9KsII3sPBtRdyNzS4rNqIlh0qIkZdrY37Ji2v17eahbiBAZ2pJPR8x1sSA3A2jaMR6SgF3sCTx0ASP1CU3HYZj4BQ)

Comment: You need to use Python 3.8 for the walrus operator to work. TIO is out of date so you need to separately choose "Python 3.8 (pre-release)". Also, I believe `int(...)` is unnecessary, because usually, a trailing `.0` does not matter.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by changing replacing the `t:=(...)//1` with `t:=int(...)` and `(t-1)` with `~-t`.

Comment: 72 bytes: [`lambda n:(t:=int((2*n)**.5+.5),(n:=n-t*~-t/2)*n-(t:=t-n),t*t+n)[2-(t<n)]`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYxBCsIwEEX3nmJ2nUmTSgMVCWbvHdRFRaOBOi1lXEipF3FTEL2Tt9FSVw8-77_Hu7nJuebhGfz2dZVglp91VV72hxLYoTgfWRCtYlIqK9KsII3sPBtRdyNzS4rNqIlh0qIkZdrY37Ji2v17eahbiBAZ2pJPR8x1sSA3A2jaMR6SgF3sCTx0ASP1CU3HYZj4BQ)

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, 22 bytes

Prompts for input matrix. Index origin = 0

```
(,m)[⍋+⌿(⍴m)⊤(⍳⍴,m←⎕)]
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlwPWooz3tv4ZOrmb0o95u7Uc9@zUe9W7J1XzUtQTI2Axk6@QC1QHVa8b@B6rl@p/GZaJgAhQ3VDBSMFUwNFAwUTBWMFMwNFSwVLBQMFcwNFIwBHKBUiYKhsZcAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 32 bytes

```
ＮθＦθＦ⊕ι⊞υ⁻×⊕κ⁺²κ×⊕ι⊕⌊⟦⁰⁻⊗κι⟧Ｉ…υθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY69DsIwDIT3PkXGWApSYe1Ylg6gDGyIoQ1BsZqfNqmRePqQIpBAeLB9vtMnK9NHFXqbc@cnWo7kBh35DE11C5GVhb1m51XUTvtFXzkCMEnJcBLsgJ4SP6HT6SczgmDSFmsn2AhF/EewXL91QaEjx8/1B7sPNNg3DOECazWVjOgX3vaptIeyujVhWl@ZVzfnbZ03d/sE) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the first `n` terms. Explanation: Based on @alephalpha's Haskell answer.

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
Ｆθ
```

Generate `n` antidiagonals, to avoid having to do square roots to find out how many antidiagonals are actually needed.

```
Ｆ⊕ι⊞υ⁻×⊕κ⁺²κ×⊕ι⊕⌊⟦⁰⁻⊗κι⟧
```

Compute the values on each antidiagonal.

```
Ｉ…υθ
```

Output the first `n` terms.